# A computable model of the natural numbers must be nonstandard?

Tags: computability, fixed-point-theorems

If I model the natural numbers with some object $0$ and an injective computable function $s$ such that $ \forall n ( s(n) \ne 0 )$. Then due to Rogers' fixed-point theorem there must be a natural number $\Omega$ for which $ s(\Omega) = \Omega $.

Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Comment: How does "there must be a natural number $\Omega$ for which $s(\Omega)=\Omega$" follow from Rogers' fixed-point theorem? Please state Rogers' fixed-point theorem and link to your source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem only gives you a number $\Omega$ such that $\varphi_\Omega$ is the same partial recursive function as $\varphi_{s(\Omega)}$ (where $\varphi_n$ is the partial recursive function computed by, say, the $n^{\text{th}}$ Turing machine). It doesn't say that $\Omega=s(\Omega).$

Comment: If this is the case then why do we have fixed point combinators that give a fixed point for any computable function?

Comment: Combinators are much more complicated than just natural numbers.  Clearly the recursive function $f(n)=n+1$ doesn't have a fixed point: there's no $n$ such that $f(n)=n.$

Comment: I get that combinators are more complicated then natural numbers.  However I've seen proofs that a fixed point combinator $ fix(f) $ always returns an $ x $ such that $ f(x) = x $ if f is computable.  So you see the source of my confusion?

Comment: Combinators open up a number of issues which can be resolved in various ways, but none of them put combinators on an equal footing with numbers/partial recursive functions. For instance, if you regard a combinator as a partial function, then the equality relation on combinators isn't computable. On the other hand, if you regard a combinator as a string (its definition), then two unequal combinators can represent the same partial function (with no way of determining whether this is true), and you can't simply think of combinators as functions (or partial functions) any more.

Comment: @Qtheplatypus You are misremembering those proofs. Rogers' theorem states (see the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Rogers.27_fixed-point_theorem)) that if $F$ is a total computable function, $F$ has a fixed point. But "fixed point" in this context does *not* mean what it usually does! A fixed point of $F$ is an $e$ such that $e$ and $F(e)$ are the same *when thought of as indices for partial computable functions* - that is, $\varphi_e\cong\varphi_{F(e)}$. (cont'd)

Comment: Similarly, a fixed point combinator $X$ takes in $F$ and outputs $e=XF$ such that $\varphi_e=\varphi_{F(e)}$. None of this gives you a number $y$ such that $F(y)=y$ - indeed, for many $F$ no such $y$ exists! I think you'll see this more clearly if you look at the proof of the fixed point theorem again.